# jQuery iterate over table elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iteration

I am trying to retrieve data from an img element inside a html web page using jQuery.

I know from the start that there is only 1 image but when I run the following code, I get 2 alert boxes. 
They contain the same information..

Does anyone know what i am doing wrong?

```
$("#tableX td").find("img").each(function() {
    if ($(this).data("apple") == "orange") {
        alert($(this).attr("src"));                
    }
});
```

Thanks.

UPDATE:

DOM output..

```
<td id="tdP4" align="center" style="border-top-width: 2px; border-right-width: 2px; border-bottom-width: 2px; border-left-width: 2px; border-top-style: solid; border-right-style: solid; border-bottom-style: solid; border-left-style: solid; border-top-color: rgb(201, 201, 201); border-right-color: rgb(201, 201, 201); border-bottom-color: rgb(201, 201, 201); border-left-color: rgb(201, 201, 201); "><img id="imgP4" src="/images/t/00.jpg" style="border-top-width: 0px; border-right-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; border-left-width: 0px; width: 63px; height: 103px; display: block; background-color: rgb(71, 7, 79); " alt="00"></td>
```

Comment: Seems like there are more than two images in the table ;) The code is fine. Do you have a link to the actual page?

Comment: can you show the html? also are the two alerts show same `src`

Comment: it would be difficult.. its very heavy on javascript and all the dom manipulation is done there. looking at the source wouldnt help. its just a basic table with some tr's and td's and 1 image per td..

Comment: Do the two alerts display the same message? That is, are the "two" images having the same `src` value? If so, you can select the first one instead of finding and looping through all.

Comment: okhay the alert is being shown because `one img per td` there must be two tds...

Comment: maybe i could see the contents of the td and see whats in there.... ?

Comment: any chance you've accidentally nested two `td` elements?

Comment: @Grant: plz tell when the two alerts show up do their values differ or they are the same

Comment: hi John, the two values are the same. I have also inspected the DOM from the developer console in chrome and there is definitely only one table, one td per tr, and 1 image!

Comment: can u plz specify what exact behavior you want because you logic shows you want to iterate through all the `img` tags and if a particuler condition meets do something,  the condition can be satisfied multiple times

Comment: There are two possible reasons: Either you have several rows containing an image (the selector selects *all* images in the whole table), or the code is run twice.

Comment: i want to be able to take action on the image element. but only when i can be certain that it is being selected correctly. yes you are right the condition may be able to be satisfied multiple times but i dont understand how it can in my situation because as i said - there is only one image on the dom! i went through the whole thing and looked...

Comment: perhaps you are correct felix.. i will take a closer look

Comment: i see 1 alert http://jsfiddle.net/wUeyK/

Comment: felix you were correct - the code was being hit twice. thank-you all for your help. if you want to create an answer i will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible reasons:

- Either you have several rows containing an image (the selector selects **all** images in the whole table)
- or the code is run twice.

Answer (score 1):

maybe try a more specific selector

```
$("#tableX td > img").each(function() {
    if ($(this).data("apple") == "orange") {
        alert($(this).attr("src"));                
    }
});
```

EDIT: your `<img>` tag is left open

Comment: sorry this hasnt changed anything.

Comment: Regarding the image tag: Als long as this is HTML and not XHTML, this is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You say

> only one table, one td per tr, and 1 image!

This allows for multiple `tr` elements, each with a `td` and an `img` inside.

The `$("#tableX td").find("img").each` will find **all** `img` elements inside the `#tableX`. It doesn't matter if they are in different rows (`tr`).

Comment: yes but like i said, there is only one image. and the alert box is telling me the source, so i know it is the same one..